# Python select and copy PDF pages to new file based on string

Tags: python, pdf

Python Noob question.
I am trying to filter a PDF file "FILEIN.pdf" for pages that contain the word "TEXT" and copy those pages to a new file "FILEOUT.pdf".
I did some tests and used values for TEXT that i know are in FILEIN to see if these pages end up in FILEOUT, but they don't, what did I do wrong in my if statement causing these pages not to show up in FILEOUT ?
Thanks.

```
import PyPDF2
pdfFileObj = open('FILEIN.pdf', 'rb')
pdfReader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdfFileObj)
pdfReader.numPages
pdfWriter = PyPDF2.PdfFileWriter()

for pageNum in range(pdfReader.numPages):
pageObj = pdfReader.getPage(pageNum)
    TEST = pageObj.extractText()
    if TEST.find("TEXT") == 1:
        pdfWriter.addPage(pageObj)


pdfOutput = open('FILEOUT.pdf', 'wb')
pdfWriter.write(pdfOutput)
pdfOutput.close()
```

Comment: Have you checked for upper/lower case "teXT" s?

Comment: Yes, I made sure to use exact same upper/lower.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

.find() returns index of found substring or -1 if not found. It may return almost any positive number (and zero). So condition may be rewritten as

`if TEST.find("TEXT") != -1:`